# c++ vector isn't showing any values i inserted

Tags: c++, vector

So I am trying to convert string to int and then store the int into vector. But when I do that and i create a for loop to display what I have stored in the vector, all i get is 0000. here is my code:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<sstream>
#include<vector>
using namespace std;
int main() {
std::string str = "<4: 3 2 1>";
vector<int> vect; 
char c;
int found;
size_t i = 0;
for ( ; i < str.length(); i++ )
{
    if ( isdigit(str[i]) )
    {
       c=str[i];
       found = c-'0';
       cout<<found<<endl;
       vect.push_back(found);
    }
}
for(int j=0;j<vect.size();j++)
{
    cout<<vect[i];
}
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: `vect[` __`j`__ `]`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`cout<<vect[i];` should be
`cout<<vect[j];` since the iterator is `j`.

Comment: @JosephAli first of all I wouldnt use such a strong word ;), but then note that the problem is not that you made a typo, this happens all the time even to experienced coders, the problem is that then you didnt do anything to diagnose what is going wrong, eg using a debugger could have helped

Comment: @JosephAli Longer and more descriptive variable names also helps. `i` and `j` are traditional and thus "Descriptive", but they look a lot alike and are pretty close on the keyboard, practically inviting this sort of mistake.